# Memory leak in WinJS when accessing a WinRT Component that returns asynchronously

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime, winjs

I've been all over the documentation and various samples, and all of my code appears to be as it should be.

However, I'm experiencing a memory leak that I cannot seem to plug. Here's what I know:

- It happens when calling into an IAsyncOperation method *and* actually attach a `.done` or `.then` to the WinJS.Promise.
- Leaking objects appear to include a `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<T>`, an `AsyncOpPromise` (dynamically created when the async method is called for the first time?) and *most importantly*, the result of the operation (T) which can be a very large object.
- I can see the apparent leaks in the JavaScript memory profiler, no matter whether the result is a number, a string, or any other object type.

For example:

```
//This one leaks
document.getImageSourceAsync().done(function(source) {
    //The intention is to do something with the image, but it doesn't really matter what does or does not happen here.
});

//This one doesn't leak
document.getImageSourceAsync();
```

I've created a sample project here: http://sdrv.ms/12TvPOa

---

Thank you in advance for any help.
Adam